# Firefox add-on to automatically log out from sites

Tags: firefox

I'm looking for a Firefox add-on that automatically logs me out from sites.

What I need:

- Automatically log out from all sites when the session is closed
- Whitelist (to let me logged in to some sites)
- Button in the status bar to easily perform a log out whenever I want to do it

I know there exists [HTTP Logout](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/http-logout/) but it works only with HTTP sites and only performs a bulk logout.

Comment: Just a raw thought: would an addon like *Cookie Controller* be suitable for that? Simply removing all cookies for a site usually has what you want as side-effect: Session gone (no session cookie), a button to act manually, and it's up to you to only accept session cookies (so permanent cookies are converted to session cookies) per site. As pointed out: not thoroughly tested, just a raw thought (aka "brain-storming aloud").

Comment: I would be very surprised if closing the session, and, thus, the TCP connection does not cause the server to log you out.  Have you tried - log in, close browser, re-open browser, revisit site? Are you still logged in. I imagine that you must be, or you would not ask, but it seems to be very strange behaviour by the servers side. Can you tell even one single site where that happens?

Comment: @Izzy I know there is that possibility but I would like a different way to do it than clearing the cache.

Comment: @Mawg well, it happens with Stackexchange for instance.

Comment: Who said clearing the cache? I was just speaking of managing the cookies (and have Firefox drop those you no longer want). Cache is not affected by that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it right. I will check out the plugin

Comment: @Mawg Removing the cookies and clearing the cache does not mean that you are truly "logged out" from the server. It only means that the server **does not recognize you**, and thus, it opens a new session ID for you. However, the old session ID is still alive (as seen by the server). Only if there is no client activity for normally around 15-30 minutes, then the server considers this as a timeout and closes the session. This is important for security reasons, because theoretically, an attacker could take over your session and continue - this is called **Session Hijacking**.

Answer (score 2):

SUPER LOGOUT is a simple site that will automatically log you out of 36 popular websites:

- AOL
- Amazon
- Blogger
- Delicious
- DeviantART
- DreamHost
- Dropbox
- eBay
- Gandi
- GitHub
- GMail
- Google
- Hulu
- Instapaper
- Linode
- LiveJournal
- MySpace
- NetFlix
- New York Times
- Newegg
- Photobucket
- Skype
- Slashdot
- SoundCloud
- Steam Community
- Steam Store
- ThinkGeek
- Threadless
- Tumblr
- Vimeo
- Wikipedia
- Windows Live
- Woot
- Wordpress
- Yahoo!
- YouTube

Warning! It starts doing so immediately when you open the site! Link: [SUPER LOGOUT](http://superlogout.com/).

Comment: please advice how to go back /stop / uninstall super logout
thanks

Comment: @joe given that it is "simple site that will automatically log you out of 36 popular websites" there is no way to unnistall it as nothing is installed.

Comment: How is a third-party site able to log a user out from other sites?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Check the source: it has JavaScript to make a load of calls to each site's logout link, like https://github.com/logout and https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout